# COM ownership with composition in interfaces

Tags: com, composition, ownership

Does a COM interface have to override `AddRef` and `Release` if it owns other interfaces?

At interface creation, members are created that maintain a refcount, so I have to override `Release` to not leak the owned interfaces when the own refcount reaches zero.

But what about AddRef? It seems like everything will be fine when just doing shallow copies of the owned interfaces. They might have a refcount below the owning interface, but can never reach zero when the owner has not reached zero.

An example of this scenario is `IDirect3DTexture9` owning many `IDirect3DSurface9` for each texture level.

Comment: What do you mean by "own" here? When a caller gets a pointer on an interface (using any method, QueryInterface or others), an AddRef has been made by the method callee. When the caller does not need the interface pointer anymore it calls Release. That's about all of COM. The caller does not use AddRef or Release return values.

Comment: @SimonMourier In my example there are child/owned interfaces created when a parent/owner is created. If the caller just Releases the created interface, the children/owned interfaces should be released aswell.

Comment: This depends on the design decision by the library author. Sometimes the "parent" owns (addrefs) the child sometimes the "child" addrefs the parent, sometimes both.

Comment: Example of "both", is old-fashioned DAO, parent owns child and child owns parent. Example of "parent owns" is ADO Recordset owns Fields. Example of "child addrefs" is ADO Recordset addrefs Connection.

Comment: @typ1232 whatever the *parent* does is the *parent's* responsibility. if it uses and allocates resources (of any kind, not just other COM objects), it should either delegate responsibility of these resources out, or release them once no longer needed, typically when released via `Release`.

Comment: If a "parent" class has a pointer to a "child" interface, than it also should have addref'd it implicitly (by calling a method) or explicitely (by calling AddRef). Same rule for everyone, there is no special "owner" behavior that would release a bunch of interface automatically.

Comment: COM object responds to external AddRef/Release calls in the way that when it gets the number of releases matching number of preceding addrefs, it self-deletes or otherwise handles this as termination of activity. That's it. It does not matter what it "owns" exactly.

Comment: Why are you talking about copies, shallow or otherwise? What is being copied where, and by whom? In what way is `AddRef` related to copying?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The resources should be freed in the destructor, or automatically if you're using smart pointer fields.  I'm assuming you're using C++.

So, indeed, inner interface pointers may have a lower reference count than the outer interface pointer.

Other than the outer pointer counting 1 towards the inner pointer's reference count, the reference counts are otherwise totally independent.